# Google Location Services getBestProvider will return null even though all location services are enabled

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

The location services getBestProvider call is returning null even though the maps app is showing the correct location. The permissions for FINE_LOCATION and COARSE_LOCATION are in the manifest.

```
public static Location getLocation(Context context) {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
    return myLocation;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the first time I've worked with location services. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you are using <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" /> as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of what provider you use GPS, NETWORK or best, all work on the same principle of getting the location from a local (on the device) cache.

Try this experiment. Change your `physical` location (move around, about 200m from where you are now) and load google maps, all of a sudden your app will return the correct coordinates too. That is because google maps knows how to trigger a local cache update. I (fortunately) have found the way to trigger that cache update.

Just call this before your getLastKnownLocation and magic will happen.

```
HomeScreen.getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }
                @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        }
    });
```

OR use LocationClient. The new API's for location updates.

Comment: This was the solution. I had to call the requestLocationUpdates on the providers.

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation` returns the **LAST KNOWN** location, if you want the **CURRENT** location you obviously have to request an update! Use `requestSingleUpdate` if you want a single location. Using `requestLocationUpdates` with `0, 0` will trigger periodical updates and drain the battery! Put a log line to `onLocationChanged` to see how often it gets called.

Comment: I'll test it out and edit my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this instread of locationmanager.getBestProvider() and see if it works for now:

```
String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
```

Also, if you pass false into getBestProvider() it will return the best Provider regardless if it is turned on or not, it will only depend on your Criteria, so it may return null if,for example, you didn't manually enable your GPS.

You may want to check this link: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider(android.location.Criteria, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29)

Comment: The answer you mentioned above is included as part of my answer. Regardless which one you choose, can you mark this post as answered? Thanks

Comment: It turns out it was not the solution. And I just noticed that it was part of your answer.

Comment: Siddharth had the right solution. I just needed to make the call for GPS, NETWORK, and PASSIVE providers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the new location api, you can find it in google_play_services_lib (https://github.com/chrulri/google-play-services_lib). Just add it to your project as an android library project. The biggest advantage of this library is that you won't have to handle GPS and NETWORK stuff, it will automatically decide, which one will be used.

Read more about it here:

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html